# Passing a function to edit state from class component to function based component through props not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, stripe-payments, react-props

I have a react frontend and most of my components are Class Based components, but it just so happens that one of the Components inside these class components has to be a functional component, so I currently have a functional component with a class based component.

Inside the functional component, I have a button that triggers a fetch call. After this fetch call is complete, I want the state of the class based (parent) component to update.

My approach was to make a function in the class based component (called setSubscriptoin) that adjusts the state of the class based component, then pass that function down to the functional component through props and call the function with a .then promise after the fetch call.

However, It appears that when I pass down the function through props, the functional component is not even able to detect the function and I get this error:
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.setSubscription is not a function`.

Here is the important code:

The class based component:

```
class OuterComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {subscription: {}}
    }

    setSubscription(subscription) {
        this.setState({subscription: subscription})
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Elements>
                <FunctionComponent setSubscription={this.setSubscription.bind(this)}></FunctionComponent>
            </Elements>
        )
    }
}
```

I wanted to include the elements part because I'm not sure if that could be effecting it. The FunctionComponent is wrapped inside a Stripe Elements provider. Not sure why that would do anything but I figured I should include it just in case.

The functional component:

```
const FunctionComponent = (props) => {
    const fetchSomething = () => {
        fetch('fetch is made here and is successful')
        .then(response => {
            if (some_condition) {
                props.setSubscription({value1: 1, value2: 2}))
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

The problem is that the function component doesn't even recognize props.setSubscription as a function (as the error says).

I've tried console logging the props variable, and it does in fact have the function setSubscription in it so I have no clue what the issue could be. I've been trying to figure this out and am completely stumped. Does anyone know why this error is happening?

Answer (score 0):

`then` should have a callback try this :

```
const FunctionComponent = (props) => {
    const fetchSomething = () => {
        fetch('fetch is made here and is successful')
        .then(()=>props.setSubscription({value1: 1, value2: 2}))  
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo in my stackoverflow question, my actual code has that. Also, the function is being called from within an if statement which might be worth noting. Do you have any idea what the issue could be in this case?

Comment: I edited the code in the question to be more accurate

Comment: i have create a sandbox for you code https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-golick-2ngjr?file=/src/Child.js

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I implemented everything here and for some reason its still giving the exact same type error. The most odd part is that if you do console.log(props), the setSubscription function shows up, but if you ever call props.setSubscriptoin(), it says the function doesn't exist. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: just create a codesandbox of your code so i can help you better .

Comment: thanks, ill try to make one. I suspect that I wont even be able to replicate the problem, because this is from a web app thats already deployed online and theres a lot of moving parts + the actual deployment process might be messing with it, but ill try right now.

Comment: Wow. the error was because I spelled the prop "setSusbcription" in the component and never noticed despite checking it three times. Sorry for wasting your time, thanks a lot for trying to help though.